# Direct or indirect contact, between web client and socket server without using Node.js

Tags: apache, sockets, client-server

[image]

- Information from the Socket Server needs to be passed to the client. (And vice versa)
- The client doesn't have to reload the page.
- Each client needs to have its own (indirect) connection.
- A connection with the socket server cannot be broken.
- I'd rather not use Node.js

I haven't come across any solutions here that don't involve Node.js. Ajax doesn't seem to be an option because it breaks connection. You would have to constantly send requests to a PHP page and keep track of which client send what to get data back, not good, way too recource intensive.

Has anyone got some ideas, what should I use?

BTW:
Socket.io seems to be good, but it involves Node.js. My host doesn't support that and I'd need to learn it first. I'd rather find something else.

Creating a connection directly from the client to the socket server would be even better, but I don't think clients can just user their browsers to connect to a socket server that doesn't use get/post etc.

Comment: What kind of socket server are you trying to connect to?  Does your host permit you to run command line applications or are you limited to a typical apache setup?

Comment: @kicken No... My host has a limited apache setup. The socket server is hosted elsewhere. It is a custom built application, similar to a telnet server. That server is hosted on a vps wich does support everything you could install on a linux machine. So there I could run an application alongside my socket server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to open a continous socket from a browser is using the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).  This API uses the [WebSocket Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) to enable bi-directional continous sockets to be opened from the browser.  You cannot open a socket to just any server though, you need to connect to a server capable of speaking the Websocket Protocol.

Node.JS is commonly used to create websocket servers because there are good existing tools to make the job easy such as [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), but it is not required. [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) is a PHP based server if you are more familar with that.  You could also modify your existing server application to speak the protocol and connect to it directly.

Comment: Thanks kicken. Ratchet looks great, but I think I'm going to go with the latter option. I'm going to make a second socket server that can accept webbrowsers' requests. Both servers are instantiated by the same program so I won't need to redirect any data.